# UITableviewController memory leak from libswiftCore.dylib

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, memory-leaks

Cannot figure out this leak. After 2 hours I resort to your help.

When I segue back to my tableview I keep getting leaks. I'm using a custom tableview cell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ClientTableViewCell
    var client = SharedData.sharedClientList[indexPath.row]
    //cell.fillData(client)

    cell.nameLabel.text = client.clientName

    var tempNeeds = client.needsAsOneStringList()

    var multipleWord = tempNeeds.removeAtIndex(0)

    var others = " | ".join(tempNeeds)
    cell.needLabel.text = "\(multipleWord) \(others)"

    cell.foundAddressLabel.text = "Map Location: \(client.placemark.subThoroughfare) \(client.placemark.thoroughfare) \(client.placemark.locality) \(client.placemark.postalCode)"
    cell.expectedAddressLabel.text = "Searched Location: \(client.importedAddress)"

    cell.hidden = false
    cell.accessoryType = .None

    if !client.isBase {
        if client.clientsBaseAssociation != nil {
            cell.hidden = true
        }
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
        cell.expectedAddressLabel.text = ""
        cell.foundAddressLabel.text = "\(client.placemark.subThoroughfare) \(client.placemark.thoroughfare) \(client.placemark.locality) \(client.placemark.postalCode)"
    }

    return cell
}
```

I did have a fillData method within the custom cell, but moved it out as I thought i may have been the cause - it wasn't. Here is the cell

```
import UIKit

class ClientTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var needLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var expectedAddressLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foundAddressLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

}
```

iOS 8.4 / Xcode 6.4

[image]

[image]

Closer to the problem

[image]

Comment: By process of elimination, doesn't it have to be in `client.needsAsOneStringList()`? Everything else is on the stack or connected to a reusable cell attribute. There's probably not enough context here for outsiders to solve this one. With ARC, mustn't it be a strong reference cycle?

Comment: will try.. and update you

Comment: Are any of those "tricky" computed properties?

Comment: It must have to do with Hidden Cells as well as - my TVC grows from 45mb to over 210 mb. Then I got this log - 2015-08-08 14:10:50.700 ClientMapping[15647:3533733] Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x1998dba80> { count = 1, contents =
 "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x1998dbe78> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>

Comment: Same error occurred when needsAsOneStringList removed, seems to be a combination of getting the info from the CLPlacemark and hiding cells.

Comment: MapView in the view segueing from is a massive memory hog!

Comment: I recommend submitting a big shebang to code review. Too much guesswork.

Comment: Also found this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42429/uitableview-hidden-section-causing-more-memory-allocations-every-time-on-pull Not that I understand the intricacies but too similar not to mention

Comment: Yeah, I've changed my design and using sections - rather than hiding cells. Hiding 200 cells was major memory issues. But the sections set up I'm using now is much better anyway. Everything happens for a reason.

Comment: @BaseZen post the hidden cells info in a question ben so I can give you some points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently (because I don't have the docs to prove it) hiding reusable table cells (`.hidden` is inherited from `UIView`) leaks memory. Perhaps when hidden it is deemed no longer re-usable, but also non-disposable. In any case the solution was to stop using that particular cell-hiding technique to manage the table view, and instead group non-displayed cells into sections that were "logically clipped" -- that is, no longer revealed to the `dataSource` and `delegate` protocol methods. (E.g. return one less for the section count, or return a zero cell count for a "hidden" section.)

Logical clipping can also work *within* a section if one is willing to do a `reloadSection()` and then dynamically recalculate the indexes so that all "hidden" cells are left out but the remaining indexes are contiguous. Depending on the size of the underlying model, one might have to get Computer-Science-y to avoid O(n^2) re-indexing algorithms.

A similar issue in Objective-C was encountered in Code Review, but was never fully explained: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42429/uitableview-hidden-section-causing-more-memory-allocations-every-time-on-pull